# Limit listed Kubernetes namespaces by access

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I have a set of `users(dev-team)` who need access only to `dev` and `qa` namespaces. I created a service account, cluster role and cluster role binding as shown below.

**Service Account**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: dev-team
```

**Cluster role**

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: dev-team-users
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["rbac.authorization.k8s.io",""]
    resources: ["namespaces"]
    resourceNames: ["dev","qa"]
    verbs: ["get","list","create"]
```

**Cluster role binding**

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: dev-team-user-bindings
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: dev-team-users
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: dev-team
  namespace: kube-system
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

When I try to verify the access 
`kubectl get namespaces --as=dev-team`

I get the below error message

```
Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden: User "dev-team" cannot list resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

I am expecting to see only `dev` and `qa` namespaces to show up. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The *list* operation fails because you are using the `resourceNames` field in the ClusterRole to restrict the namespace objects to grant access too but *list* would return *all* namespace objects.

**But I guess what you really want is to restrict access to the resources *in* a namespace, and not the namespace objects themselves (which contain not much more information than the name of the namespace).**

To achieve this, you have to create Roles (or a ClusterRole) and RoleBindings in those namespaces that you want to grant access to the users.

Here is how you can grant access to all resources for the `dev-team` user in the `dev` and `qa` namespace but deny access to any resources in any other namespace.

Create a ClusterRole (you could also create a Role in the `dev` and `qa` namespaces, but using a ClusterRole allows you to define the permissions only once and then reference it from multiple RoleBindings):

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: dev-team-users
rules:
- apiGroups:
    - '*'
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
```

Create a RoleBinding in both the `dev` and `qa` namespaces:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: dev-team-user-bindings
  namespace: dev
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: dev-team-users
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: dev-team
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: dev-team-user-bindings
  namespace: qa
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: dev-team-users
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: dev-team
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Test access:

```
kubectl get pods -n qa --as=dev-team           # Succeeds
kubectl get pods -n dev --as=dev-team          # Succeeds
kubectl get pods -n default --as=dev-team      # Fails
kubectl get pods -n kube-system --as=dev-team  # Fails
```

See [Kubernetes RBAC documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/).

### EDIT

**1. Identify namespaces a user has created**

Can't do this with RBAC. You would need some form of [auditing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/).

**2. Identify namespaces a user has access to**

Also can't do this easily with RBAC. But you could just iterate through all namespaces and test whether a given user has access:

```sh
for n in $(kubectl get ns -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}'); do
  echo -n "$n: "
  kubectl auth can-i get pods -n "$n" --as=dev-team
done
```

You can vary the verb/resource part (e.g. `get pods`) as needed.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I have a requirement to identify all the namespaces a user has created or has access to. Is there a way to list it based on RBAC rules?

Comment: Is there a way to have "kubectl get ns" to only list the namespaces a user has access to? Natively or via extending kubernetes by functionality?