# How to restrict access for namespaces like "kube-system" in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, open-policy-agent

We want to provide a cluster for our customers with pre-installed applications and therefore want to give the customer all rights except on the namespaces provided by us and the system namespaces, such as "kube-system", so that they cannot see the sensitive informations in secrets or break anything there. We have already tested with OPA, but unfortunately you can't intercept GET requests there, which means the secrets would still be viewable.
It also doesn't work with RBAC because you can't deny access to a particular namespace there.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks and best regards

Vedat

Comment: have you tried with `Role` support in K8s? I know a little about RBAC and think it should be possible. Also, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59062716/limit-listed-kubernetes-namespaces-by-access.

Comment: yeah I ried rbac already, but I must create a rolebinding in every namespace i want to access and I can only give permissions to namespaces that already exists. What I want is to leave an user all permision and only restrict/exclude one namespace.

Comment: Hello @Vedat, could you clarify if I understand correctly that your Kubernetes cluster is a fully managed solution by you (and the team presumably) and it's not any of the available cloud-managed solutions?  From the perspective of your comment under one of the answers. Is this [Kubernetes webhook authorization with minikube](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-webhook-authentication-authorization-with-minikube-67b2b385ffd1) something you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by giving the user a ClusterRole that only has permissions on namespaces and a ClusterRole that has permissions on everything. I bound the ClusterRole for the namespace with a ClusterRoleBinding and the other ClusterRole with a RoleBinding.
So that the user also has permissions on the namespaces he dynamically creates he needs a RoleBinding on the ClusterRole that is allowed to do everything.

To do this automatically, I use the tool Argo-Events, which triggers a RoleBinding deployment on a namespace creation event.
And with OPA I prevent that the user can change or delete namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely use OPA to evaluate GET requests, just not through the admission controller (as that ultimately decides what will be persisted in Kubernetes, and GET requests by nature only read). What you'll want to use is a Kubernetes [authorization webhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/webhook/), which you can add to the chain of authorizers consulted for any request. [Here](https://sbueringer.github.io/kubernetes/open-policy-agent-authorization-webhook/)'s a pretty good blog post on the topic.

Some caveats to take into consideration:

1. You'll need full control of the cluster in order to configure the API server with custom authorizers. This is currently not possible with many of the managed cloud offerings.
2. Not supported in popular tools like Gatekeeper, i.e. you'll need to deploy and manage "vanilla" OPA for this.

Comment: Thanks for replying, the blog post looks good but unfortunately it doesn't describe exactly how to do it with Authorization Webhook. Do you know any example how I can implement something like this?

Comment: @Vedat, Hello. You can find some example solutions with the Kubernetes Policies Controller with OPA to control users access: [1](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper/tree/d2470993769e1c02f22c1a155a35c43076892d88/deprecated), [2](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sbueringer/a5b755a6db50d0f52ea6a2c8f1998445/raw/8a3be58da7d14cd9d665ef7ac9939d6a4b6e5fd8/blog-opa-example1.rego.rb). Also here you can find a OPA playground for policy validation: https://play.openpolicyagent.org/

Comment: @Vedat here's another pretty good article on the topic: https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-webhook-authentication-authorization-with-minikube-67b2b385ffd1 
It doesn't use OPA but the principles are the same for setting everything up.

Comment: @DawidKruk Hey David, thanks for replying, unfortunately OPA can't intercept GET-Requests, like kubectl get secrets.

Comment: @Vedat OPA absolutely can intercept GET requests such as `kubectl get secrets`, when used as an authorization webhook